# BigQuery resources exceeded with huge query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The following query cannot change. This query is used to select all active users from the beginning of time when I started tracking them using Firebase and BigQuery. I use this query to export the data into my own database so my projects can query faster.

This query here is just two of the datasets that I would be querying, in my actual query it is more like 100+ datasets that are unioned together.

Everytime I run the fully constructed query I get the following error:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex..

```
 WITH allTables AS (SELECT
    app,
    date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 30  THEN users END) as days_30
  FROM (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
      dates.date as date,
      periods.period as period,
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as users
    FROM `TBL1.*` as activity
    CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC') as date
      FROM `TBL1.*`
      CROSS JOIN
          UNNEST(event_dim) as event) as dates
      CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
          period
        FROM (
          SELECT 30 as period
        )
      ) as periods
      WHERE
        dates.date >= TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC')
      AND
        FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dates.date, TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY)/periods.period) = 0
      GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2 
  UNION ALL SELECT
    app,
    date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 30  THEN users END) as days_30
  FROM (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
      dates.date as date,
      periods.period as period,
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as users
    FROM `TBL2.*` as activity
    CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC') as date
      FROM `TBL2.*`
      CROSS JOIN
          UNNEST(event_dim) as event) as dates
      CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
          period
        FROM (
          SELECT 30 as period
        )
      ) as periods
      WHERE
        dates.date >= TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC')
      AND
        FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dates.date, TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY)/periods.period) = 0
      GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2 ) SELECT
   app as target,
   UNIX_SECONDS(date) as datapoint_time,
   SUM(days_30) as datapoint_value
 FROM allTables
 WHERE
   date >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Day, 'UTC'), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
 GROUP BY date,1
 ORDER BY date ASC
```

I read that removing the `ORDER BY date ASC` could help, but it did not in my case. Is there a way that I could allow BigQuery to use more resources as this query won't get run too often and a minor price spike would be acceptable. '

BigQuery response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "resourcesExceeded",
        "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex."
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex."
  },
  "query": ""
}
```

Most recent job JSON:

```
{
      "status": {
        "state": "DONE", 
        "errorResult": {
          "reason": "resourcesExceeded", 
          "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.."
        }
      }, 
      "kind": "bigquery#job", 
      "statistics": {
        "endTime": "1493215173261", 
        "creationTime": "1493215171094", 
        "startTime": "1493215173261"
      }, 
      "jobReference": {
        "projectId": "premium-apps", 
        "jobId": "bquijob_4aad2106_15baa8f26b9"
      }, 
      "state": "DONE", 
      "id": "premium-apps:bquijob_4aad2106_15baa8f26b9", 
      "errorResult": {
        "reason": "resourcesExceeded", 
        "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.."
      }
    }
```

Comment: Alas, additional slots will not help with "Not enough resources for query planning"

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Limiting data is not an option and I deleted that last post because it was completely unstructured and not clear on what I wanted. I think this question better explains what I'm trying to do instead of just asking how to fix my error.

Comment: @JoeScotto please give a failed job id. And please keep the old question as well. It really helps. We are humans, versioning is important, and we don't want to be fooled.

Comment: @Pentium10 I don't have a failed job ID. This is being run via the .net API.

Comment: every job has an ID, try to find out, the response should have the job id. Also if you are not then use whatever console to list most recent jobs and find out which one is the problematic job id: `bq  ls -j -a --max_results=15`

Comment: @Pentium10 Still looking for the jobid but I added the response I get in the question. The query of course would have my query but it's more than 2k lines with it.

Comment: @Pentium10 Found the jobid: `bquijob_4aad2106_15baa8f26b9`

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky does it help you?

Comment: In addition to job id I will need a project id if possible.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky Please take a look at my updated question, I included the entire response from the job.

Comment: Ack - I got all the details, looking into it.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky Any updates on this? Still having issues trying to figure it out.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky I did some testing and found that running a single query from the giant cross join query will return an error for a higher billing tier required. Is it possible that many of them are returning this same error and therefore causing bigquery to get confused on what the actual error is?

Comment: I can tell with certainty that the original error is not related to cross join errors - original error happens during query compilation, well before runtime kicks in. I am still figuring out how to solve it.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky I'm fairly certain now that it's related to the billing tier being too high. I've pulled out just a single query from the giant one and it gives me billing tier too low errors. I'm experimenting now with just limiting the data to a few tables at once now but am having issues with the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740267/how-to-limit-datasets-using-table-suffix-on-complex-query