# BigQuery - Query planning used too many resources - What to do?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a medium complicated query with only some 60 rows and 4 joins of maximum 1M rows tables. However the query does not run and returns the following error:

> **Error:** Query planning used too many resources

Is there a simple way to solve it? I only use `JOIN EACH` and `GROUP EACH BY` but it does not help. (This was suggested in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636268/bigquery-resources-exceeded-with-huge-query))

In addition, yesterday the query ran and returned results but since this morning there is this error.

Comment: It may be that you were very close to the limit before and a small change to the schema or query caused this. What if you use standard SQL instead? Can you share the query itself?

Comment: Please share more details: Query, job id, or anything that will help the community understand the problem better.